# Error en prepare() de una consulta preparada mysqli en PHP

Tags: php

Buen día a todos, tengo la siguiente función:

```
function mostrar_producto_carrito($conexion){
    try{
        $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("select p.nombre,c.cantidad,(p.precio*c.cantidad) as total from producto p inner join carrito c on p.id = c.id_producto");
        if($sentencia){
            $sentencia->execute();
            $sentencia=$sentencia->get_result();
            return $sentencia->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);        
            $sentencia->close();
            cerrar_conexion($conexion);
        }
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Me sale el siguiente error:

> Warning: mysqli::prepare(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda-virtual\admin\general\funciones.php on line 155

Esta es la función de conexión que le paso de parámetro a la función anterior:

```
function conexion(){
    try{
    $conexion = new mysqli('localhost','root','A6R7u5c6','dbvirtual_store');
    return $conexion;
    }catch(mysqli_sql_exception  $e){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar, gracias.

Comment: En este caso tu código no amerita una consulta preparada por una razón muy simple: **no hay nada que preparar**. Usa `query` en vez de `prepare` , quitando el `execute` por supuesto y debería funcionar.

Comment: ya lo probé como me dijiste, y me sale este error: Warning: mysqli::query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\tienda-virtual\admin\general\funciones.php on line 155

Comment: Podrías agregar tu archivo de conexión a la base de datos?

Comment: claro, ya lo agregue

Comment: Podrías verificar si no estar cerrando tu conexión antes de llamar a tu función: `mostrar_producto_carrito()`

Comment: si eso era, en un método anterior cerraba la conexión. Gracias por su ayuda

Comment: @U.C de nada, excelente tarde.